# MQTT wks31.js unknown property

Tags: javascript, mqtt, pebble-watch

I am developing a watchface with MQTT support for the pebble smart watch.
I am using mqttws31.js on the JS side of the app (running on an android phone).

After some time (minutes) I get this error message printed at the log:

Uncaught Error: Unknown property, mqttVersionExplicit. Valid properties are: timeout userName password willMessage keepAliveInterval cleanSession useSSL invocationContext onSuccess onFailure hosts ports mqttVersion

mqttVersionExplicit is used by the mqttws31.js script, I do not use it.

I'm connected to the MQTT broker iot.eclipse.org via websocket.

Has anyone experienced this error? Could somebody help me with this issue?

Thanks,
Johannes